# Unit test of component when using Ant Design with Form.create

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, antd

I have the following React Component

```
import React from "react";
import { Form, Input } from "antd";

class FormDataImportProtocol extends React.Component {
  callMyMethod = (id) => {
    //...code...
  };

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.form.validateFields((err, values) => {
      if (!err) {
        callMyMethod(values.dummyvalue);
      }
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;

    return (
      <>
        <h2>Heading</h2>
        <Form layout="horizontal" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <Form.Item label="dummy">
            {getFieldDecorator("dummy", { initialValue: "dummy" })(
              <Input />
            )}
          </Form.Item>
        </Form>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default Form.create()(FormDataImportProtocol);
```

And I want to test that callMyMethod(str) is called. The problem is the wrapping of Form.create()(...)

How can I unwrap Form.create() in my test? Thanks for any advice.

Comment: can you explain what is that `Form.create()`?

Comment: You can stub `Form.create` for starters.

Comment: @estus: Do you have a code snippet for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I read the documentation again and found the solution for my problem:

```
describe("Test suite", () => {
  let  formRef;

  it("My test case", () => {
    const EnhancedForm = Form.create()(FormDataImportProtocol);
    const wrapper = mount(
      <EnhancedForm wrappedComponentRef={form => (formRef = form)} />
    );

    // formRef is my ref which I need for my spy:
    spy(formRef, "createDataImport");
  });
});
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I tried to follow this method but getting an error createDataImport method is not found.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do that in v4 as in antd v4, Form.create() has been removed

Answer (score 1):

if you do not need that `Form.create()` in your test, yo can do this

`export default Form.create()(FormDataImportProtocol);
export const FormTest = FormDataImportProtocol;`